# rabbitmq AlreadyClosedException

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using the rabbitmq server with a java application. When the application receives a message on a particuliar queue, it generates some data and sends them on another queue.

When running the application, it receives the message, generates the data and sends them on the right queue. The data are well received on the server and they are correct. But when the application tries to send an acknowledgement to the server, I get an AlreadyClosedException.

I have the following message in the logs of the server: closing AMQP connection.

Here is the code of the handleDelivery function, in the rabbitMQ consumer class:

```
public void handleDelivery( String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, asicProperties properties, byte[] body )
        throws IOException {
    actionManager.receivedSelectedData( body );
    getChannel().basicAck( envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false );
}
```

Here is the code in the method receivedSelectedData(), where the data are generated before being sent:

```
public void receivedSelectedData( byte[] body ) {
    differentialEquations = differentialEquationsObjectManager.fromBytes( body );
    timeSeriesCollection.removeAllSeries();
    for ( int i = 0; i < differentialEquations.size(); i++ ) {
        differentialEquation = differentialEquations.get( i );
        for ( int j = 0; j < differentialEquation.getSystems().size(); j++ ) {
            try {
                generator = new NumericalMethod( differentialEquation, j );
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                timeSeriesCollection.addSeries( generator.equationToTimeseriesRK4( 10.0 ) );
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    sender.publish( RabbitMQGenerateSender.GENERATE_DATA_QUEUE_NAME,
            timeSeriesCollectionObjectMnanager.toBytes( timeSeriesCollection ) );
    }
```

The queue seems to be correctly declared, here is my queue declaration:

```
protected void declareQueue( String queueName ) {
        try {
            channel.queueDeclare( queueName, true, false, false, null );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

and the channel declaration:

```
try {
            connection = factory.newConnection();
            channel = connection.createChannel();
            int prefetchCount = 1;
            channel.basicQos( prefetchCount );
        } catch ( IOException | TimeoutException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have some other applications using rabbitmq with the same channel and queue declaration parameters and they work well. I only have one application that systematically fails when sending acknowledgment.

Here is the getChannel() method:

```
public Channel getChannel() {
    return channel;
}
```

Comment: provide some code how you receive message and send response

Comment: I added the code, hope it helps

Comment: How is the receiver queue is declared? Is it set to AutoDelete true? If so an Ack will throw an exception.

Comment: Please add also your getChannel() method code.

Comment: I added the getChannel() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The receiver queue must be declared as `AutoDelete = false` if ACK functionality is to be supported.
Here is an example in C# (there might be small differences than Java)

```
private bool PushDataToQueue(byte[] data, string queueName, ref string error)
{
    try
    {
        if (_connection == null || !_connection.IsOpen)
            _connection = _factory.CreateConnection();

        using (IModel channel = _connection.CreateModel())
        {
            if (AutoCloseConnection)
                _connection.AutoClose = AutoCloseConnection;
            // Set the AutoDelete as false, fourth parameter!!!
            channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);
            channel.BasicPublish("", queueName, null, data);
            if (!channel.IsClosed)
                channel.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        error = string.Format("Failed pushing data to queue name '{0}' on host '{1}' with user '{2}'. Error: {3}", queueName, _factory.HostName, _factory.UserName,
            e.GetCompleteDetails());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I added the receiver queue and channel declaration, it looks like the queue parameters are correct.

Comment: redmood, you should also implement the check if the connection is not open and create new connection if not, as it shown in the example.

Comment: I did implement the check connection, I also implement a check channel in case and it fixed the problem. Thank you very much.